# Change HTML of multiple child elements (what is JS version of this jquery selector?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm going through my code to replace jQuery with JS where needed, there are some instances where I need to clear and rebuild some table data, for that I use jQuery in the following way:

```
$("[id*='mg_row_document'] td:nth-of-type(2)").html('');
```

and what I was able to put together for pure JS is this, but doesn't work I only get a NodeList of elements and then would have to loop through el to do getElementsByTagName. Is there a way of changing them all at once like with jQuery?

```
el = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mg_row_document"]');
el.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: If a jQuery selector worked for you before, just reuse it with `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize that works. Makes things much easier!

Comment: see answer, because you're not out of the woods yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your jQuery selector worked for you before, then reuse it with `querySelectorAll()` but keep in mind , that it is not a jQuery collection which are ready to go. Instead you will have a NodeList which you need to iterate through using a loop. Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* target is a NodeList. A NodeList is an
|  array-like object, but not a real array.
|  The first half of this selector is most
|  likely not needed. If given the real HTML 
|  we'd know for sure.
*/
var target = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='mg_row_document'] td:nth-of-type(2)");

// Determine the number of tds in NodeList
var qty = target.length;

/* This for loop is saying:
|  "`i` starts at 0 (i=0)...
|  ...For each iteration (for)...
|  ...while `i` is less than (i < )...
|  ...the total amount of `td`s (qty)...
|  ...`i` will increase by 1 (i++)...
*/
for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

  /* Using bracket notation to specify 
  |  the index position of each `td`.
  |  Each iteration, the `style` property
  |  is used to change each `td` background
  |  color to yellow.
  */
  target[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id='mg1_documentA'>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentA1'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentA2'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentA3'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentA4'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='mg1_documentB'>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentB1'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentB2'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentB3'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentB4'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='mg1_documentC'>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentC1'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentC2'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentC3'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='mg_row_documentC4'>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ah I guess there's no escaping looping. Oh well, at least it's still slightly easier than I thought, thanks.

Comment: Your code can be shortened: `for (let i = 0, target = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='mg_row_document'] td:nth-of-type(2)"); i < target.length; i++)`

Comment: You're welcome @nick, Yeah at first loops are a pain, but you'll get used to it, happy coding.:)

Comment: @connexo true, but I break things down line for line so the beginners will see the guts of the source better.;)

Comment: Yeah, you added those immensely helpful comments after my comment here. Well crafted answer!